# How do you call a private module function from inside a class?

Tags: python

I have a module that looks something like this:

```
def __myFunc():
    ...

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.myVar = __myFunc()
```

and I get the error:

```
NameError: global name '_MyClass__myFunc' is not defined
```

How can I call this function from inside the class?

edit: Since posting this, I've discovered I can avoid the automatic mangling by using a single underscore instead of double underscores.  I was using two as per "Dive Into Python", which only states a double underscore denotes private functions.

Comment: Step 1: Don't use `__` double underscores.  Ever.  There's no point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because Python's compiler replaces method calls (and attribute accesses) inside classes if the name begins with two underscores. Seems like this also applies to functions. A call to a method `self.__X` would be replaced by `self._ClassName__X`, for example. This makes it possible to have pseudo-private attributes and methods.

There is absolutely no reason to use two underscores for functions inside the module. Programmers often follow the convention of putting *one* underscore in front of the function name if the function shouldn't be called from outside.

Using two underscores is only necessary for attributes/methods in classes if you don't want them to be overwritten by subclasses, for example. But there are few cases in which that is useful.

Comment: "But there are few cases in which that is useful".  As a practical matter, there are zero cases in which this is useful.